# Why is this link not working?

Tags: javascript

I want to make email contact available to my visitors without being easy prey for address harvester spam. The HTML as I have now is:

```
            <span id="email">Email</span>
            <script>
                var link = ('<' + 'a' + ' ' + 'h' + 'r' + 'e' + 'f' + '=' + 
                  '"' + 'm' + 'a' + 'i' + 'l' + 't' + 'o' + ':' + 'c' + 'j'
                  + 's' + 'h' + '@' + 'c' + 'j' + 's' + 'h' + '.' + 'n' +
                  'a' + 'm' + 'e' + '?' + 's' + 'u' + 'b' + 'j' + 'e' +
                  'c' + 't' + '=' + 'T' + 'o' + '+' + 't' + 'h' + 'e' + 'A'
                  + 'u' + 't' + 'h' + 'o' + 'r' + '>' + 'E' + 'm' + 'a' +
                  'i' + 'l' + '<' + '/' + 'a' + '>');
                console.log(link);
                document.getElementById('email').innerHTML = link;
            </script>
```

The JavaScript console has the correct link logged, but nothing I've tried gets the email span to be populated with the link. I also (shudder) tried document.write(), but that didn't do anything. There are no errors on the JavaScript console.

Why are neither of these approaches working yet?

Comment: it's so messy to read...

Comment: What on earth is that...

Comment: Could you not use smaller fragments or store it backwards and just invert the string?

Comment: you miss a " at the end of the link <a href="mailto:cjsh@cjsh.name?subject=To+theAuthor>Email</a>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `link` variable comes out as `'<a href="mailto:cjsh@cjsh.name?subject=To+theAuthor>Email</a>'`, so it looks like you're missing a closing quotation mark.

Try

```
var link = ('<' + 'a' + ' ' + 'h' + 'r' + 'e' + 'f' + '=' + 
              '"' + 'm' + 'a' + 'i' + 'l' + 't' + 'o' + ':' + 'c' + 'j'
              + 's' + 'h' + '@' + 'c' + 'j' + 's' + 'h' + '.' + 'n' +
              'a' + 'm' + 'e' + '?' + 's' + 'u' + 'b' + 'j' + 'e' +
              'c' + 't' + '=' + 'T' + 'o' + '+' + 't' + 'h' + 'e' + 'A'
              + 'u' + 't' + 'h' + 'o' + 'r' + '">' + 'E' + 'm' + 'a' +
              'i' + 'l' + '<' + '/' + 'a' + '>');
```

Comment: However, SO can answer.... +1 for your effort

Answer (score 0):

Try to close href string. Your result html is `<a href="mailto:cjsh@cjsh.name?subject=To+theAuthor>Email</a>`